# Can I run a Ubuntu Eucalyptus Cloud on a single-machine?

Tags: untagged

HI,

Seems from the chatter I found on the web that there is a way to install a Eucalyptus on Ubuntu Cloud using a single machine (with some limits on using EBS storage and managed networking).

Does anyone know of a tutorial or a how-to page that can lead me through such an install?

Thanks for all your help.

Bye,
  RaamEE-IL

My current status is that I have a single server with quad-core and 8GB of memory which is running Ubuntu Cloud (UEC) 10.04 and Eucalyptus 2.00.

I can't run instances of images I uploaded. I get an error "FinishedVerify: Not enough resources (0 < 1: vm instances."

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in
http://kiranmurari.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/uec-cc-nc-single-machine/

Also, for a script that autoinstalls everything on a single machine (interestingly an ec2 instance) check this out http://foss-boss.blogspot.com/2010/10/cloud-on-cloud-uec-on-ec2.html

You will however want to comment the part in the script where the hypervisor is changed to be qemu

Good luck :)